# Math typesetting bug when a question is closed.

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22815/pi-4-how-to-disprove

I have noticed this before as well. When a question is marked duplicate and  closed, the possible duplicate question appears at the beginning of the post but there is a math typesetting error when it inserts the duplicate link at the beginning of the post. (Theo Buehler did the edit for it to appear properly but I undid it so that the bug can be seen)

**EDIT** Any update of this bug being resolved?

**EDIT** Looks like this issue which was raised nearly 3 months before has not yet been resolved. The same problem occurs for this question as well https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37630/how-to-express-log-p-q-if-log-p-4-m-and-log-sqrt2-q-n

**EDIT** Another evidence of this bug (May 14th)

[Is the $\sum\sin(n)/n$ convergent or divergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36732/is-the-sum-of-sinn-n-convergent-or-divergent/36734#36734)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up again, I was thinking of bumping this question because I'm as annoyed with this as you seem to be.

Comment: If the issue was raised before it might be helpful to provide a link so no one reinvents the wheel.

Comment: @Gerry: Not 100% sure, but I guess it was raised before on Feb 19 at 18:27 `;-)`

Comment: @Gerry: The issue was raised on Feb 19th for the question "Pi=4? How to disprove?". I noticed the same issue yesterday as well for "how to express logpQ if logp4=m and log2√Q=n". Hope this is now clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, on MathJax enabled sites we won't escape `\` in titles moved to the post body if the title contains a `$`.

There are some other possible edge conditions but this fix should suffice for now.