# Duplicate banner breaks LaTeX

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, closing, exact-duplicates

On several *recent* occasions, after closing a question as a possible duplicate the automatic banner breaks the $\LaTeX$ requiring manual intervening.

I don't recall it was like that before, and I suppose that something was changed in the way the system fetches the question's title. It does not break in the announcing comment automatically added when first suggesting a duplicate, though.

One recent example is [Vector space over $F_p$ not the union of $k\leq p$ subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/149553/622), but I recall doing that at least once more in the past week.

Comment: It always was like that since I'm here, it was brought up a long time ago [in this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1677/5363). I don't quite understand the fix that was made but obviously it doesn't really work or at least it doesn't handle all exceptions.

Comment: @t.b.: Interesting. Well, I guess that [status-completed] is not really completed after all. (Perhaps a recent change broke the fix?)

Comment: No, I don't think so. I seem to remember to have fixed broken LaTeX in duplicate links during the entire time I'm here.

Comment: @t.b.: Your first comment here is from two minutes, that's not a long time. :-P (I don't remember fixing duplicate banners before last week and I don't remember anyone else fixing... but my memory is huge holes in it.)

Comment: Here's an example of an [older post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/76545/5363) where a similar thing happened as in the example you bring up here. Just in case it is related: [here's another meta-question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3973/5363) where problems with inequality signs were brought up.

Comment: @t.b.: I see. Then I suppose either the developers see that the problem persists, or once again we'll have a "next deployment..." and [status-completed].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in build rev 2014.1.21.1317

Comment: Was this really fixed? [Today's report](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13319/127096).

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to [the bug t.b. linked to in comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/math-typesetting-bug-when-a-question-is-closed). However, the issue there was caused by escaping backslashes (with another backslash) in order to prevent them being [interpreted incorrectly by the Markdown renderer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44319/backslashes-in-duplicate-titles-break-inserted-links) (not necessary within MathJax).

This one involves escaping already-escaped HTML entities. Greater-than and less-than symbols are normally escaped automatically when the title is formatted for the duplicate link. When processing MathJax sections, ampersands are escaped. So > becomes `&amp;gt;` in the final output, which doesn't do anything good.

Comment: My experience is that when someone copy-paste a compiled MathJax output the result is HTML. It seems as though the dup. banner is doing something similar, although not exactly.